# Get file from server using SFTP/SCP which requires user switch on jump host

Tags: ssh, openssh, sftp, scp

I'm trying to find an instant way to get to connect the ServerB, which is behind the firewall, through Server A  and exchange files between Server B and my laptop.

Normally, the ssh login process looks like this.

1. My Laptop->MiddleMan:

`mylaptop:  ssh myUser@ServerA` (password auth)

2. MiddleMan->Destination:

`ServerA:   sudo -u sharedUser ssh ServerB` (no password)

I have to login to Server A using a restricted account **myUser** first, switch **myUser** to **sharedUser** on Server A, since only that **sharedUser** have the key for Server B. I don't have the key for Server B, and I have no privilege to r/w using myUser on **Server A**.

I've tried the one [OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies and Jump Hosts](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts), but it won't work because the myUser for Server A does not have the key (sharedUser on Server A has it) for logging in Server B.

```
      ssh                 sudo su                   ssh
Me -----------> myUser@A ---------> sharedUser@A -----------> B
       ^                     ^                        ^
   password              switch user        using sharedUser@A's
authentication                                     ssh key
```

Questions:

1. I would like to know if there is a way to connect to Server B "directly" through SSH Proxy, or something else?
2. Is there a method to remotely exchange files with Server B using SFTP/SCP.. etc thorough serveral hops and username change?

Thanks!

Comment: Edited. Actually I am asking for a way to transmit files between server behind several hops and local machine

Comment: What is your platform on the local machine?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl linux(centos 7)

Answer (score 2):

From `mylaptop` you can run a command on `ServerA` like this: `ssh myUser@ServerA some_command`. So this should be possible:

```
ssh -t myUser@ServerA sudo -u sharedUser ssh ServerB
```

Normally `ssh` that is supposed to run `some_command` doesn't allocate a pseudo-terminal, it only passes stdin, stdout, stderr. If you'd like to interact as if `ssh ServerB` was typed manually on `ServerA`, pseudo-terminal is needed. Therefore `-t`.

Pseudo-terminal would also be useful if `sudo` or the "inner" `ssh` asked for password.

You said you'd like to transfer files. The "inner" `ssh` can run a command on `ServerB` like the "outer" `ssh` runs a command on `ServerA`. The command may be `cat`, a file can be transferred (streamed) this way. In this case you shouldn't use `-t`, it would only mangle with the stream. Fortunately your `sudo -u sharedUser ssh ServerB` needs no password, so there's no conflict in whether to use `-t` or not.

To pull a file from `ServerB`:

```
>/local/file ssh myUser@ServerA sudo -u sharedUser 'ssh ServerB "cat </server/b/path/to/file"'
```

To push a file to `ServerB`:

```
</local/file ssh myUser@ServerA sudo -u sharedUser 'ssh ServerB "cat >/server/b/path/to/file"'
```

Proper quoting is very important to make the redirection just after `cat` affect `cat` (not `ssh` or `sudo`).

Comment: That's cool, could this help for scp/sftp file transmission between server B and laptop?

Comment: @oscarxvita My answer now introduces a basic way to stream files. It's not exactly what you asked in the above comment though.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski There is some SSH output at the beginning and end but it works!

Comment: @jmiserez Probably some scripts like `~/.bashrc` print something. Use cases like this are the reason such scripts should remain silent.